# calculate distance from centre

Tags: classical-mechanics

I have the following question:

[image]

And i am asked to calculate the distance, d,.

However, i am unsure how to do this. I know that in order for the see-saw to be in equilibrium then both sides should have equal weights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

You have to balance out the turning force on both sides.

$1 \times 400 = 0.5 \times 200 + d \times 250.$

Solve for $d$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the see saw is in rotational equilibrium, net torque acting on system is zero. Hence, we have: 
$$(400*1.0) - (200*0.5) - (250*d) = 0$$